# Orientdb concurrent issue - Timeout (5000ms) on acquiring lock on record #46:0 on server 'node75'. It is locked by request 0.324309

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm using orientdb 2.22 in distribute environment, when i use concurrent thread to write the data and it occurs such exception

Error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedRecordLockedException: Timeout (5000ms) on acquiring lock on record #46:0 on server 'node75'. It is locked by request 0.324309
    DB name="graphics"
    DB name="graphics"
```

Below is my code:

I will create the sql by my java code, and then using java api to execute it.

java code:

```
OrientGraph graph = getOrientGraphTx();
graph.command(new OCommandScript(sql)).execute();
```

sql:

```
BEGIN <br/>
 LET a0 = CREATE EDGE tic FROM #17:0 TO #52:0<br/>
LET a1 = CREATE EDGE trip FROM #17:0 TO #28:0<br/>
LET a2 = CREATE EDGE tmtel FROM #17:0 TO #59:0<br/>
 COMMIT RETRY 0<br/>



RETURN [$a0, $a1, $a2]<br/>
```

I have some questions:
a. is that possible if a connection disconnected, and the record still locked?
b. how long the lock will be released? is there any way to unlock the recored?
c. Is there any better way to avoid such exceptipn?

Thanks

Comment: Please use OrientDB 2.2.26 because many issues have been fixed since 2.2.22.

Comment: i used version 2.2.26, but the same problems.

Comment: Can you enable the FINE logging level and upload the log somewhere?

Comment: please see the next answer, since the log is too much to past as comments. thanks

Answer (score 0):

how to re-produce it:

scenario 1:

I config the replication in a-synchronized mode. in my application, i point to just one node on my cluster, like remote:192.168.2.3/graphics, when i shutdown this node, it start to throw exception:

ODistributedRecordLockedException: Timeout (5000ms) on acquiring lock on record #46:0 on server 'node75'.

On the server side, the fine log shows:

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1312: canceled (locks=[] undo=0 startedOn=Thu Aug 24 10:16:55 CST 2017 thread=12) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1312: rolling back transaction on database 'graphics' (undo=0 tx=false) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1322 on database 'graphics' is expired after 32111ms [ODistributedDatabaseImpl$8]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1322: canceled (locks=[] undo=0 startedOn=Thu Aug 24 10:16:56 CST 2017 thread=12) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1322: rolling back transaction on database 'graphics' (undo=0 tx=false) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1327 on database 'graphics' is expired after 31518ms [ODistributedDatabaseImpl$8]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1327: canceled (locks=[] undo=0 startedOn=Thu Aug 24 10:16:57 CST 2017 thread=12) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1327: rolling back transaction on database 'graphics' (undo=0 tx=false) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1337 on database 'graphics' is expired after 30206ms [ODistributedDatabaseImpl$8]
2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1337: canceled (locks=[] undo=0 startedOn=Thu Aug 24 10:16:58 CST 2017 thread=12) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1337: rolling back transaction on database 'graphics' (undo=0 tx=false) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1332 on database 'graphics' is expired after 30967ms [ODistributedDatabaseImpl$8]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1332: canceled (locks=[] undo=0 startedOn=Thu Aug 24 10:16:57 CST 2017 thread=12) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:965 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction 0.1332: rolling back transaction on database 'graphics' (undo=0 tx=false) [ODistributedTxContextImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:970 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1562 cannot lock records [#20:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #104:-5, #116:-4, #120:-3] because owned by 0.1563 (retry 5/10, thread=110) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:971 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1563 cannot lock records [#20:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #104:-5, #116:-4, #120:-3] because owned by 0.1447 (retry 5/10, thread=105) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:971 FINE  [mac15] Starting distributed transaction on database 'graphics'... (reqId=0.1565 thread=109) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:971 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: registered request 0.1565 in database 'graphics' (thread=109) [ODistributedDatabaseImpl]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:976 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1558 cannot lock records [#19:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #101:-5, #114:-4, #117:-3] because owned by 0.1560 (retry 9/10, thread=113) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:977 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1564 cannot lock records [#19:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #101:-5, #114:-4, #117:-3] because owned by 0.1560 (retry 1/10, thread=112) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:28:977 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1560 cannot lock records [#19:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #101:-5, #114:-4, #117:-3] because owned by 0.1447 (retry 6/10, thread=115) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:29:025 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1561 cannot lock records [#20:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #104:-5, #116:-4, #120:-3] because owned by 0.1447 (retry 6/10, thread=114) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:29:030 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1559 cannot lock records [#19:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #101:-5, #114:-4, #117:-3] because owned by 0.1447 (retry 7/10, thread=111) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:29:067 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction: 0.1558 cannot lock records [#19:-2, #26:0, #43:0, #53:0, #101:-5, #114:-4, #117:-3] because owned by 0.1447 (retry 10/10, thread=113) [ODistributedTransactionManager]

2017-08-24 10:17:29:067 FINE  [mac15] Distributed transaction cannot be completed, wait 12ms and retry again (1/10) [ODistributedStorage]

Comment: When you said "I config the replication in a-synchronized mode", what do you mean for a-synchronized? Could you please share your distributed configuration?

Comment: {
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": "majority",
  "executionMode": "asynchronous",
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "newNodeStrategy": "static",
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please try to replace "asynchronous" with "undefined".

Comment: OK. let me try it and will let you know if it works, and thanks in advance. And I have a little confused, according to the official document, it suggest to use asynchronous replication (http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Configuration-Tuning.html), so what's the difference? Since i tried to set it as synchronous before, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `asynchronous` was fundamental before 2.2.x. After 2.2.0 we improved the replication algorithm (bypassing Hazelcast queues) and now the difference is very little with 3 servers. I think it's a bug somewhere we're going to fix, of course. But for now, please use `synchronous` ;-)

Comment: it works now, thanks very much. is "undefined" the same as "synchronous"?

Comment: undefined means synchronous, unless you specify something different via API.

Comment: It is a little wired. I set it as synchronous but it doesn't work, but it works when i set it as undefined. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.